# Ploting a function with BigFloats values in Julia

Tags: function, plot, julia, bigfloat

I have a function ( lets call it test(M) ), that "spits out" only BigFloats, like shown below.

```
test(100)
22.48487818538224586950434052086250350042005040604872584710165219826379165499864
```

I would like to plot this function. Howver, it seems that this doesn't work for big Floats. 
I even tried to use  `round(Int8, test(x))` in order to make the results smaller, but it still didn't work.

```
using Plots 

M = 1:10
plot(test.(M), xaxis=:log)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It works for a random function I made up as below:

```
using Plots
test(x) = BigFloat(rand()) * 100 + x * rand()
M = 1:10
plot(test.(M), xaxis=:log)
```

So, perhaps your test() function is not returning a proper vector of BigFloats, ie has `Inf` or such?